# How to use properties from a property file within a Maven script?

Tags: maven, properties

I want to use properties that are defined in a property file in a Maven script, in a plugin configuration section. How can I do that?

Extract from my Maven script:

```
...
<configuration>
    <url>${jdbc.url}</url>
</configuration>
...
```

And my property file (jdbc.properties) is somewhere in my classpath

```
jcbc.url=some.url.to.use
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [properties plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/). And it's called a POM, not a script. It may seem like a trivial difference, but a POM describes a project and how it should be built, where a script is a sequence of commands saying what needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks, and point taken for the POM. I'm mostly used to Ant scripts, but I can see the difference in concept.